# Solspace Calendar Entries are duplicated if they share the same day

Tags: solspace

I'm displaying events as a list (per day) but finding that if a day has more than one event, the day is duplicated, so rather than:
1
2
3
I'm getting
1
2
2
3
where there is more than one event on the 2nd,
code is here:

```
<ul class=" calendar_list no-bullet">
                        {exp:calendar:cal 
                            {if segment_3 == ''}date_range_start="year-month-01" date_range_end="year-month-last"{/if}
                            {if segment_3 != ""}date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-01" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last" {/if}
                             {if segment_4 == "{current_time format="%m"}"}date_range_start="today" date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-last"{/if}

                            pad_short_weeks="n" 
                            category="1" 
                        }
                             {if calendar_no_results}<h3>There are no events for this month</h3>{/if}
                            {!-- {if event_count=="1"}<h1>****{event_start_date format="%F %Y"} | {event_count}</h1>{/if} --} {!-- control date format here for month/year title --}
                            <li class="calendar_list"><h4>{event_start_date format="%j"}<br /><span class="list_month">{event_start_date format="%M"}</span></h4>{!-- control date format here for day/month sub-title i.e. %j = day  %F = month  --}
                                <p>{embed="_embeds/calendar_events_by_day" my_date="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{event_start_date format="%d"}" event_cat_id="1"}</p>
                            </li>
                        {/exp:calendar:cal}
                    </ul>
```

and embedded code '**calendar_events_by_day**' here:

```
{exp:calendar:events 
    date_range_start="{embed:my_date}" date_range_end="{embed:my_date}"
    category="{embed:event_cat_id}"
}
    <div class="{if event_type == "Event Type 1"}event_type1{/if}{if event_type == "Event Type 2"}event_type2{/if}{if event_type == "Event Type 3"}event_type3{/if}{if event_type == "Event Type 4"}event_type4{/if}">
    <a href="/{segment_1}/events/{url_title}" class="tips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{event_title}">**{event_title}</a><br />
    {if session!=""}{session}<br />{/if}{event_start_date format="%g"}{if event_start_minute > 0}:{event_start_minute}{/if}{if event_end_time != event_start_time && event_end_time != '00:00'}&ndash;{event_end_date format="%g"}{if event_end_minute > 0}:{event_end_minute}{/if}{event_end_date format="%a"}{if:else}{event_start_date format="%a"}{/if}<br /></div>
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> ### Highly suggested reading to distinguish Calendar tags:
>
> https://solspace.com/docs/calendar/getting_started/

You should only need `{exp:calendar:cal}` to display events for a day. No `{exp:calendar:events}`, no embeds.

Let's say you have this URL:
`http://example.com/calendar/events/2015/12/25`

To display events on December 25th, 2015, you would need only this:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
  date_range_start="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
  date_range_end="{segment_3}-{segment_4}-{segment_5}"
  pad_short_weeks="n"}

    {events}
        // Your event data
    {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

(Add conditionals based on segment_X if you want something a bit more dynamic. `{current_time}` is a late-parsed variable, however, so might not parse early enough for the `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag)

If the range is *more* than 1 day and you want to display events for each day, you would add the `{display_each_day}...{/display_each_day}` tag pair around `{events}...{/events}` so that Calendar loops through each day.

Comment: Thanks will check out the guide, my situation requires the latter (more than 1 day and you want to display events for each day) as I want to avoid – example: 23 October repeating 2 times,
i.e

NOT
23 October
Event 1
Event 2
---
23 October
---
Event 1
Event 2
---

BUT
23 October
Event 1
Event 2
---
24 October
Event 1
---
etc

Thanks